# Other tags questions are also in [stackoverflow-for-teams] tag: Is it a bug?

Tags: bug

I think there are only four questions for [stackoverflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams).

[image]

But there are lots of questions on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams. Many of them are not tagged as [stackoverflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams).

Is it a bug?

Comment: @Catija Thanks. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug... the tag [channels](/questions/tagged/channels) is [synonymized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow-for-teams/synonyms) to [stackoverflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams) but they don't seem to have been merged, which is why the [channels](/questions/tagged/channels) tag still exists but, as far as the system is concerned, questions that are tagged [channels](/questions/tagged/channels) *are* tagged [stackoverflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams) and future questions will swap from [channels](/questions/tagged/channels) to [stackoverflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams) by default.

Whether they should have been merged or not... that's unknown to me. Joe Friend made the synonym, so we could ask him.

Comment: I don't know that why you are receiving down votes since your answer is correct for my question.